# Commands or script to clean out media folder of unwanted filetypes

Tags: scripts, files

I have a media download folder with all sorts of irrelevant files e.g. readme, txt and torrent files in addition to the mp4, avi, mp3 and other valid media files.

I want a script or a set of commands i can run to clean it out via `cron` or something on a regular basis and go through all directories and sub directories removing unneeded files.

Comment: So what are needed and what are not-needed files? Be specific about any one type..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file with the extensions you want to remove, one per line (say, `dontwant.files`):

```
.txt
.nfo
.torrent
.csv
```

Combine `find` with `grep`, `xargs` and `rm`:

```
find /path/to/media/directory -type f -print0 |
  grep -zFf /path/to/dontwant.files |
  xargs -0 rm
```

- `find` with `-type f` and `-print0` will print out the names of all the files it finds separated by the ASCII NUL character - the only one which is perfectly safe for delimiting paths and filenames.
- `grep`with `-z` separates lines by the ASCII NUL character, so that each filename output by `find` is treated as a separate line. `-F` disables regex matching, and `-f` reads in patterns from the file.
- `xargs` with `-0` reads in lines separated by ASCII NUL characters, and uses them as arguments for the command, in this case `rm`.

This is easily converted to the the other approach (remove all but some extensions). For example, with a file like `want.files`, containing:

```
.mp4
.srt
.avi
.mp3
```

only the `grep` command needs changing, using `-v` to negate matches:

```
grep -vzFf /path/to/want.files |
```

Comment: I like the negate method using -v better. Thank you sooo much for this beautiful and thorough answer. I think its the best answer I have ever seen in the Universe. :-) Much thanks.

Comment: @NormanBird don't be so sure. Do remember to test by using `echo` instead of `rm`. :)

Comment: when I ran the echo test with find m:// -type f -print0 | grep -zFf dontwant.files | xargs -0 echo    and it returned a huge lump of what appears to be all files, those in the dontwant,files and also those I wanted to keep. Looks like all the files..  Please note I am running command from my windows computer from my Git Bash command prompt to search my samba share drive m:// which is ubuntu.

Comment: @NormanBird Pick one subdirectory of it, run the command, and post the results to http://paste.ubuntu.com. Did you leave an empty line in `dontwant.files`?

Comment: [Here is the paste bin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10872864/)

As you can see above it is returning all files in the directory. I do not have .mp4 in the dontwant.files. I also made sure there is no space at the end

Comment: @NormanBird you're not running the command on Ubuntu, are you? Please run on Ubuntu and report back. Or ensure that the versions you have on windows have the necessary options. Also post the `dontwant.files`, if you can.

Comment: You are correct, when run on Ubuntu machine it only returns the list of unwanted files specified in the file. Im satisfied with this, just cant do it with bash from windows machine is all. I will do a seperate question for that :-). Much thanks.

Comment: @NormanBird you'll probably want to post on [su], if you do ask a new question. In any case, check the options that the Windows `grep` has - does it support `-z`?

Answer (score 2):

The script below cleans up your directory recursively. It can be run from either `cron` or a shortcut key combination. The use is simple:

1. Copy it into an empty file, save it as `clean_up.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the extensions to remove, in the line:

   ```
   remove = [".txt", ".log"]
   ```
3. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/clean_up.py <directory_to_clean_up>
   ```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

#--- set the extensions to remove below
remove = [".txt", ".log"]
#---

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, file)
        if any([file.endswith(s) for s in remove]):
            os.remove(file)
```

#### The negative option

If you'd like to do it the other way around: only *keep* specific file types (extensions), remove all others, use the (version of the) script below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

#--- add all extensions you'd like to keep below
keep = [".mp4", ".mp3"]
#---

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, file)
        if all([not file.endswith(s) for s in keep]):
            os.remove(file)
```

To add either one of the scripts above to a shortcut: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
python3 /path/to/clean_up.py <directory_to_clean_up>
```

Comment: This answer is equally juicy , thank you. I like the idea of using the command line shown by heemayl above, which I can create an alias for. thanks again though.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what we have got so far from your question:

**Find and Remove:**

If you want to remove all files having `.txt` or `.torrent` extension:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.torrent' \) -execdir rm {} +
```

Alternately, if you want to remove all files that do not have `.mp3`, `.mp4` or `.avi` extension:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -not \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.avi' \) -execdir rm {} +
```

Here we have used `find` with OR `-o` option to get our desired files, when we have found the files we removed them by calling a single instance of `rm`.

**Cron:**

If you want to run it as a `cron` job, you can put the command in your user's `crontab` entry with when you want `cron` to run this. For example, to run this on Sunday 11:00 PM every week:

```
00 23 * * 0 find /path/to/dir -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.torrent' \) -execdir rm {} +
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about special characters with `-execdir`. A `-execdir rm {} +` is `-print0 | xargs -0 rm`, without the middleman - `find` will ensure arguments get passed properly.

Comment: @muru: Thanks..did not know that..from manpage `any given invocation of command will only list files that exist in  the  same subdirectory` ..that sums it up nicely..